# Angular ui-sref not generating href links

Tags: angular-ui-router

I've went through many SO posts related to `ui-sref` not generating properly, but they did not seem relevant to my issue so I'm posting another.

I am working on a simple navbar with links to the Welcome state and the Login state. The `<a ui-sref>` tag does not generate a working href in the browser. Upon inspect, only the original HTML shows up.

**app/assets/templates/nav.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a ui-sref="welcome" class="navbar-brand">Hitch</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a ui-sref="welcome">Home</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a ui-sref="login">Login | Register</a></li>
        <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
    (function () {
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, AuthProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });

        $stateProvider
            .state('welcome', {
                url: '/',
                controller: 'WelcomeCtrl as welcome',
                templateUrl: "welcome.html"
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                controller: 'AuthCtrl as auth',
                templateUrl: "login.html",
                onEnter: function(Auth, $state){
                    Auth.currentUser().then(function(){
                        $state.go('welcome')
                    })
                }
            })
            // other states


        $httpProvider
            .defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

    }   

    angular
        .module('hitch', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'ngResource', 'Devise', 'ui.bootstrap'])
        .config(config);
})();
```

**NavCtrl.js**

```
(function() {
function NavCtrl($scope, Auth, $rootScope) {

    this.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated;
    this.logout = Auth.logout;

    Auth.currentUser().then(function(user) {
        $rootScope.user = user;
        console.log(user);
    });

   // other functions 

};

angular
    .module('hitch')
    .controller('NavCtrl', ['Auth', '$rootScope', '$scope', NavCtrl]); })();
```

I am inserting the navbar into my `application.html.erb` via a `NavDirective.js`.

```
(function() {
function navBar() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'nav.html',
        controller: 'NavCtrl'
    }
}

angular
    .module('hitch')
    .directive('navBar', [navBar])})();
```

When I tried using regular `<a href>` tags, links worked just fine. I'm still relatively new to Angular - are there any glaring errors in my code that are causing the `ui-sref` to not work correctly? How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance!